# I want to put the text in pyqt QCalendarWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to put the text of `p.drawText (r.x () + 10, r.y () + 33, '{} / {}'. Format ('tset1', 'test2')` condition on the selected `QCalendarWidget` date. But it is not good.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class main_window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(main_window, self).__init__()
        self.resize(1280, 900)

        self.Calendar() 

    def Calendar(self):
        self.cal = QCalendarWidget(self)    
        self.cal.resize(500, 500)
        self.cal.clicked.connect(self.Calendar_click)

    def Calendar_click(self):
        p = QPainter()
        r = QRect(0,0,10,10)
        d = self.cal.selectedDate()
        self.cal.paintCell(p, r, d)
        if (d == QDate.currentDate()):      
            f = QFont()
            f.setPixelSize(10)
            f.setBold(True)
            f.setItalic(True)
            p.setFont(f)
            p.drawText(r.x()+10, r.y()+33, '{}/{}'.format('tset1','test2'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = main_window()
    main.show()
```

I've tried many, but I still do not know how to put small text on the selected date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to overwrite the `paintCell()` method since this method is called in paintEvent():

```py
class CalendarWidget(QCalendarWidget):
    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        super(CalendarWidget, self).paintCell(painter, rect, date)
        if date == self.selectedDate():
            painter.save()
            f = QFont()
            f.setPixelSize(10)
            f.setBold(True)
            f.setItalic(True)
            painter.setFont(f)
            r = rect
            painter.drawText(
                rect.topLeft() + QPoint(10, 33),
                "{}/{}".format("tset1", "test2"),
            )
            painter.restore()


class main_window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(main_window, self).__init__()
        self.resize(1280, 900)
        self.Calendar()

    def Calendar(self):
        self.cal = CalendarWidget(self)
        self.cal.resize(500, 500)
```

---

**Update:**

If you want the text to remain, you must save the date and repaint if necessary since Qt repaints everything

```py
class CalendarWidget(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CalendarWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self._selected_dates = set()
        self._selected_dates.add(self.selectedDate())
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    @pyqtSlot(QDate)
    def on_clicked(self, date):
        self._selected_dates.add(date)

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        super(CalendarWidget, self).paintCell(painter, rect, date)
        if date in self._selected_dates:
            painter.save()
            f = QFont()
            f.setPixelSize(10)
            f.setBold(True)
            f.setItalic(True)
            painter.setFont(f)
            r = rect
            painter.drawText(
                rect.topLeft() + QPoint(10, 33),
                "{}/{}".format("tset1", "test2"),
            )
            painter.restore()
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you. Lastly, I would like to keep one selected text, but what should I do?

Comment: @Lee I do not understand you, explain yourself better, do you want the text to remain even when another date is selected?

Comment: Yeah If you select a different date, this is how you keep the text.

Comment: Thank you :) It is difficult but very helpful.